# Having trouble cleaning up my code

Tags: jquery

I have 4 functions that do something I feel one can do.

```
function getDownline(rankid, args, type) {
    $('body').append('<div class="modal">');
    $.getJSON('message_center_getMessageLists.asp', args, function (json) {
        var options = '';
        $.each(json.downline, function (i, item) {
            options += '<option value="' + item.distID + '" title="' + item.name.toLowerCase() + ' (' + item.distID + ')" >' + item.name.toLowerCase() + ' (' + item.distID + ')</option>';
        });

        $('#fromList').find('option')
            .remove()
            .end();

        $('#fromList').append(options);
    })
    .success(function () { $('.modal').remove(); })
    .error(function () { 
        alert("There was an error while trying to make this request;  If it persists please contact support"); 
        $('.modal').remove(); 
     });
 }
```

The only real difference is the `json.downline` it can be 4 different things.  I added the `type` param.  Which I was trying to use to pass in `downline, sponsor, pSponsor or monitorlist`.

But I can't seem to just do `json.type`, or `json. + type` any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json[type]` will get the property named by `type`.